# How to filter columns containing dates in format yyyyMmm?

Tags: python, pandas

I am working on a data that looks like that:

```
      unit  coicop geotime  2020M07  ...  1996M04  1996M03  1996M02  1996M01
122    IA5  CP5261     AAT      NaN  ...    84.43    84.60    84.52    84.85
7630   IA5  CP5261     AAT      NaN  ...    62.60    62.72    62.66    62.91
23690  IA6  CP5261     AAT      NaN  ...    99.70    99.90    99.80   100.20
```

What would be the best way to filter specific years? Let's say I'd like to filter columns containing data from 2005. Or in two specific years 2010 and 2015?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert all columns without first 3 to datetimes:

```
df = df.set_index(['unit','coicop','geotime'])
df.columns = pd.to_datetime(df.columns, format='%YM%m')

print (df)
                     2020-07-01  1996-04-01  1996-03-01  1996-02-01  \
unit coicop geotime                                                   
IA5  CP5261 AAT             NaN       84.43       84.60       84.52   
            AAT             NaN       62.60       62.72       62.66   
IA6  CP5261 AAT             NaN       99.70       99.90       99.80   

                     1996-01-01  
unit coicop geotime              
IA5  CP5261 AAT           84.85  
            AAT           62.91  
IA6  CP5261 AAT          100.20
```

Then you can filter like:

```
df1 = df.loc[:, df.columns.year.isin([2010, 2015])]
```

Another approach is use [`DataFrame.filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) with values contains in columns names joined by `|`:

```
df1 = df.filter(regex='2010|2015|unit|coicop|geotime')
```